# Custom TF 2.0 training loop performing considerably worse than keras fit_generator - can't understand why

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, keras, training-error

In trying to better understand tensorflow 2.0, I am trying to write a custom training loop to replicate the work of the keras fit_generator function. In my head, I have replicated the steps fit_generator takes to train my network, but this is clearly not the case as the network trains significantly better using fit_generator as opposed to my training loop (my loop: MAE ~3.0, keras fit_generator: MAE ~2.0).

Below is my class:

```
class CRNN(tf.keras.Model):
def __init__(self):
    super(CRNN, self).__init__()
    # Consider LocallyConnected1D
    self.conv1 = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=50, strides=1, padding='same',
                                        activation=None, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', name='conv1a')
    self.pool1 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=100, strides=None, name='pool1')
    self.gru1 = tf.keras.layers.GRU(units=32, name='gru1')
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=16, activation=None, name='dense1')
    self.output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='relu', name='output1')
    self.lrelu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1)
    self.mae = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0, nesterov=True)

def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.conv1(inputs)
    x = self.lrelu(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.gru1(x)
    x = self.dense1(x)
    x = self.lrelu(x)
    return self.output1(x)

def train_step(self, sample, label):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = self.call(sample)
        loss = self.mae(label, predictions)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.trainable_variables))
    self.train_loss(loss)

def eval_once(self, sample, label):
    predictions = self.call(sample)
    loss = self.mae(label, predictions)
    self.eval_loss(loss)

def train(self, num_epochs):
    self.train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
    self.eval_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='eval_loss')
    self.store_gradients = np.empty((num_epochs, ))
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        start_time = time.time()
        self.train_loss.reset_states()
        self.eval_loss.reset_states()
        for samples, labels in train_gen:
            self.train_step(samples, labels)
        train_gen.on_epoch_end()
        for samples, labels in val_gen:
            self.eval_once(samples, labels)
        print('Epoch: {0}, Time: {1:.2f}, Train Loss: {2:.2f}, Test Loss: {3:.2f}'.format(epoch + 1,
                                                                                          time.time() - start_time,
                                                                                          self.train_loss.result(),
                                                                                          self.eval_loss.result()))
```

I am using two custom generators (both are tf.keras.util.Sequences), one for the training data and one for the validation data, but they are used for both training strategies, so I don't feel like they are the issue.

In order to implement my custom training loop, I run:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
model = CRNN()
model.train(20)
```

In order to run keras fit_generator, I run:

```
model2 = CRNN()
model2.compile(optimizer=model2.optimizer,
               loss=model2.mae)
history2 = model2.fit_generator(generator=train_gen,
                                validation_data=val_gen,
                                epochs=20,
                                workers=1,
                                use_multiprocessing=False,
                                verbose=2,
                                callbacks=[])
```

I feel like I must be missing something extremely obvious here, can anyone help me out? Please let me know if I neglected to give any other important/relevant information. Thanks so much!

Edit: I have also tested this model on a single input in order to verify that it is capable of over fitting. Both are able to over fit to a single data point.

Comment: This would have much greater chance of getting answered on TensorFlow support forum since this is an issue with TensorFlow (if not bug).

Comment: do you shuffle in your train loop? fit generator shuffles by default, right?

Comment: I don't think fit_generator shuffles by default, but the training generator definitely shuffles.